# Making a function component from a class component. What is props here?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I was trying to implement a drag and drop functionality to my ant design tabs component. The example they mentioned in the documentation is class based. I was trying to make it into function component but I am not sure what props are in this case.

[Ant design demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cgxyf?file=/index.js:394-411)

[Official documentation](https://ant.design/components/tabs/#components-tabs-demo-custom-tab-bar-node)

For example, I got confused here, this class component itself is outside another class component. How would react extract these `connectDragSource`, `connectDropTarget`, `children` when it has noting that is being passed from the props? And how would I extract these when I am in a function component?

```
class TabNode extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { connectDragSource, connectDropTarget, children } = this.props;

    return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(children));
  }
}
```

and there are some other aspects in the provided demo that are confusing to me. It would be great help if you could breakdown and explain what is happening so that I can turn this into a react functional component.

Comment: Can you update your question to include *your* attempt at converting a class component to a React function component? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure will do tonight.. meanwhile I just put it in a separate file and I import it in my functional component, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

In functional component you can access `props` as one of your component's argument, and also instead of returning your `JSX` by `render` method, whatever you returns by your functional component, considers as your `JSX` output, like this:

```
function MyComp(props){
 // do whatever you want by props (actually body of your function is equivalent to render method in class component)
 return (<div>...</div>);
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-tabs-antd-4-18-2-forked-8f3f3?file=/index.js)  I implemented your tab example by function component.